# Maintain the SelectedNodeStyle of treeview while navigating Treeview on masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Hi all i applied selectednodestyle for a treeview which works fine when i am not navigating. But on navigating i am unable to see the applied color for the treeview selected node. Here is my design in master page

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewCategories" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" Style="min-height: 200px;
        max-height: 500px;" NodeIndent="0" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="LeafNodesStyle" CssClass="TreeView"
        NodeStyle-CssClass="NodeStyle" ParentNodeStyle-CssClass="ParentNodeStyle" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="RootNodeStyle"
        SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle" LeafNodeStyle-Width="100%" NodeStyle-Width="100%"
        ParentNodeStyle-Width="100%" RootNodeStyle-Width="100%" Font-Size="12pt">
        <Nodes>
            <asp:TreeNode Text="All Items" NavigateUrl="~/Default3.aspx" SelectAction="SelectExpand"
                Value="All Items">
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Hello" Value="Hello"></asp:TreeNode>
            </asp:TreeNode>
        </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
```

This is my `css`

```
<style type="text/css">
    .TreeView
    {
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #B2B2B2 !important;
    }
    .TreeView div
    {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .TreeView table
    {
        border-top: 1px dotted #B2B2B2 !important;
    }
    .TreeView div table
    {
        border-bottom: none !important;
        border-top: none !important;
    }
    .TreeView table td
    {
        padding: 2px 0;
    }
    .LeafNodesStyle
    {
    }
    .RootNodeStyle
    {
    }
    /* ALL ELEMENTS */.NodeStyle
    {
    }
    .ParentNodeStyle
    {
        /*background:yellow;*/
    }
    .SelectedNodeStyle
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #6799D1;
        display: block;
        padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
    }
</style>
```

But i am unable to apply the color for selected node after navigating to a page can any one help me

Answer (score 1):

your codes are working Ok so is the CSS. if you will notice the text of the one youve selected became **bold**.

If your basis is in change of color of the text, there is some problem. If you would look at the source code, not only **SelectedNodeStyle** css style is applied on the item, but these also

```
NodeStyle FooterContent_TreeViewCategories_2 LeafNodesStyle FooterContent_TreeViewCategories_8 SelectedNodeStyle FooterContent_TreeViewCategories_10
```

so I suggest putting some !important on your css color for the change in color to take effect.

```
.SelectedNodeStyle
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6799D1 !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 3px;
}
```

Comment: where should i change now in order to work out as per my requirement

Comment: just add !important on your SelectedNodeStyle css class. see above.